# HTML checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display and hide a table using a checkbox. The table appears and disappears with no problem . But the checkbox is not getting checked . I have Jquery v1.8.2 . i have the following code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#checkbox').toggle(function() {
            document.getElementById('table').style.display = "inline";
        }, function() {
            document.getElementById('table').style.display = "none";
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
    <br />
    <table id="table" style="display: none;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" name="file">
                <input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this way -

```
$('#checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $('#table').show();
    } else {
        $('#table').hide();
    }
});
```

Working demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/pmNAe/

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$('#checkbox').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $('#table').show();
    } else {
        $('#table').hide();
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/xjcRG/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Jyud3/)

Note: You can use change instead of click but but change get fired only after blur in firefox.

```
$(function(){

    $('#checkbox').click(function (){
           if(this.checked){
               $("#table").show(); 
          }else{
               $("#table").hide();  
         }
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try like

```
$('#checkbox').click( 
    var my_dis = document.getElementById('table').style.display;
     if(my_dis == 'inline')
        document.getElementById('table').style.display = "none";
     else   //if(my_dis == 'none')
        document.getElementById('table').style.display = "inline";       
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the solution in this fiddle:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JRQMN/)

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    var $table = $("#table");

    if($this.is(":checked"))
        $table.show();
    else
        $table.hide();
});
```